# QuickTimeInstaller causing me buckets of issues

Tags: bsod, quicktime

Today I saw this message:

[image: dialog]

After it installed and I rebooted, I was getting the Blue Screen of Death every few clicks.

So...to resolve, I restored to a Restore Point when all was working, 2 days ago.

Then, QuickTime reappeared and tried to reinstall itself.

Is this iTunes related? or might it be related to Windows Live Messenger?

Any suggestions on how to stop this auto installation?

Update:

Rolling back to a previous Restore Point temporarily fixed the issue but the patch was automatically applied a second time. Then, I made the horrible mistake of uninstalling iTunes and this caused my previous old restore point to be wiped away because of a limited amount of space that I alloted to the Windows Restore functionality.

I fear that I will be faced with many issues ahead...

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize this window from any of the quicktime installs/updates I've ever done.

I'd suggest that you go directly to the apple site and download the quicktime installer directly.

I'd also suggest running a malware scan using malwarebytes just in case it's not legit.